# How to add and manage a new network interface into android stack

Tags: java, android, network-interface

I have developed a network driver for the mobile linux kernel.
My network device (pif0) run well with

```
ifconfig pif0 10.22.2.15
ping -I pif0 8.8.8.8
```

Now i want that android stack be able to track this device and to set it as the default gateway to internet.

I think that i should develop a number of java classes to track my new interface and manage it, but i don't know how to make them in the good order.

any one who have made this exercise can advice please?

Answer (score 0):

Treat the network as an ethernet interface.

You can either use the default name of "ethx" for you interface. In your case, rename `pif0` to `eth0`. This will cause it to match as an ethernet interface which will cause it to be tracked by the android stack. This should almost assuredly work for your use case.

The other option would be to update the android resource overlay `config_ethernet_iface_regex` to match your naming scheme of `pifx`.

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem, my interface come up then down, my interface is a modem driver, it is not correctly managed by the ethernet tracker

Comment: It comes up then down because nobody is using it and `ConnectivityService` tears it down in that case. Depending on which version of Android you are using, file a `NetworkRequest` by either `StringNetworkSpecifier` or `EthernetNetworkSpecifier`. You can file this before the network comes up in which case it won't get torn down, or you can file it after in which case it should be brought up. By filing the request, it let's `ConnectivityService` know this network is needed and not to tear it down.

Comment: can you develop your response into a little pseudo code, or a java code, your reponse sounds good, I'm not an expert in android java part, but i start to understand by reading your response, i'm using android 11

Answer (score 0):

The response is dependent to each vendor, but in general, when the RIL makes setup data call, it enables the NIC interface, then it sends the data connection information to the java RIL part, then the information is sent to the connectivityService which creates a network agent to manage the NIC interface, then the netd sets the routing table and necessary firewall rules.

This may vary from vendor to an other